# TypeScript: How to calculate the number of days from date to today

Tags: typescript

```
const calculateDays = (joinedDate: string) => {
   const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
   const today = new Date();
   const joined = new Date(joinedDate);
   const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((today - joined) / oneDay));
 //                                        ^       ^
 //                                        error   error
   return diffDays;
 };
const days = calculateDays('2019-12-10T05:49:42.366Z')
```

The error I get is `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JavaScript calls the valueOf method to convert an object to a primitive value

Typescript still can't "understand" this pattern. Relevant [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2361)

As workaround you can coerce to number:

```
const today = +new Date();
const joined = +new Date(joinedDate);
```